# Can webfonts be non-utf compatible?

Tags: css, utf-8, fonts, webfonts

I'm not sure what else to blame... But I've tried everything, including reconverting original tff to web fonts using squirrel converter.

The font in question is this:  http://www.fonts2u.com/bolnisi.font
The description it says: `Unicode BMP only` whatever this means :)

On the demo, I see that text in html had been entered in latin characters.
When I use Georgian utf letters: `ქართული`. This font never applies!

Example: http://mac.idev.ge:800/breakmedia/ Look at the header, only numbers are transformed into this font. Rest is normal serif.

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bolnisiregular';
    src: url('font/bolnisi-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/bolnisi-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/bolnisi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/bolnisi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/bolnisi-webfont.svg#bolnisiregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

html *
{
   font-family: 'bolnisiregular' !important;
}
```

What is happening here? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a typical "hack" font. As you can see on the font page you link to, the glyphs are not at the character code they're supposed to belong to. The glyph at the code point for "i" is "ი". That's not the correct glyph for "i". The glyph for "i" is supposed look like "i". The glyph "ი" belongs at code point U+10D8, the code point for the Georgian letter "IN".

Such font hacks are/were used before the code points for that language became officially ratified in the Unicode standard, and/or for software in that language which does not (yet) support Unicode. I.e., sometime in the dark ages there existed no official encoding for the Georgian language, yet people in Georgia wanted to see Georgian glyphs on their screens. So arbitrary ASCII code points were overloaded with Georgian glyphs. Strictly speaking, that font is broken.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks for explaining :) This font for example: http://www.fonts2u.com/dejavu-sans-bold.font?ptext=%E1%83%91%E1%83%9A%E1%83%90&submit=Submit displays georgian letters correctly, but I cannot find letters in the character map... so how does this one work?

Comment: Use the drop down at the top of the charmap and choose the Georgian section. It's simply not displaying the whole charmap all at once, because it's huge.

Comment: Hey, you seem to know a lot about fonts, can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759286/web-font-doesnt-get-applied-font-face

Answer (score 0):

This specific font has Latin letters only which you can see in `Character map` section below the example text on fonts2u.com.

Comment: That's what I thought. Is there a way to remap it to unicode?

Comment: AFAIK that would be complicated. It is possible using JavaScript (or better jQuery), but you would need to create table of chars with Latin letters as keys and Georgian letters as values and then read whole text letter-by-letter "translating" it with this table.

Comment: Hey, your answer was short and to the point. But I think other one offers more information, which was exactly that I needed! SO +1

Comment: That's ok. I don't do it for rep :P