# web font doesn't get applied! @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I'm struggling with web fonts, I'm using DejavuSans to display Georgia ქართული text.

Unfortunately it doesn't get applied and I'm out of ideas.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVuSans';
    src: url('font/DejaVuSans.eot');
    src: url('font/DejaVuSans.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/DejaVuSans.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/DejaVuSans.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/DejaVuSans.svg#bolnisiregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body
{
   font-family: 'DejaVuSans' !important;
}
```

I downloaded it from here: http://www.fonts2u.com/dejavu-sans.font

And I applied it here: http://mac.idev.ge:800/breakmedia/

Chrome inspector tells me that css is correctly overwritten, but where are the fonts themselves??

Comment: and the path to the web font you specified wrong?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me...?! At least the text shows up correctly, can't really tell what font it's being rendered in though.

Comment: @AlexWilson don't think so, I'm not getting 404.

Comment: @deceze it is standard serif that gets rendered :(

Comment: although now looked through firebug shows that this font is used

Comment: The http://mac.idev.ge:800/breakmedia/ page declares `font-family: "bpg_ingiri_arial"` of `body`. Where are expected to see DejaVu Sans?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm experimenting with different webfonts, thinking it was file corruption or something :/

Comment: So there is no specific error description, no reproduceable case.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela There is, font-face doesn't work! with any web font.

Answer (score 1):

Urls are relative to the folder containing the css file. So your url to the font needs to be absolute and point to the root e.g:

```
/font/DejaVuSans.eot
```

or relative and point to one folder up:

```
../font/DejaVuSans.eot
```

etc depending on where your stylesheet and fonts are located.

Comment: urls are correct.
css.css is in root font folder is
font/font-file. As I said I don't get 404.